# How can I apply the numpy modulus/remainder operation to a list of datetimes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-datetime

In Python 3, I have a list of `datetime` objects that I would like, using `numpy`, to wrap (python modulus `%` operator) by dividing by a fixed time period represented as a python `timedelta`. The goal is to derive a `numpy` array containing the remainders.

Consider:

```py
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
t=[]
for i in range(10):
    t.append(datetime.strptime('1066-10-1%i'%i, '%Y-%m-%d'))

delta_t = timedelta(days=2)

# Apply np.fmod(), but run into type conversion difficulties
```

How can I use `numpy` to achieve the equivalent of the following operation?

`t_mod = t % delta_t`

I have tried converting to `numpy` `datetime64` and `timedelta64` objects, so far in vain. I am happy to flesh out error messages if that would be useful, or provide any other information people may require.

Broader question: If this works for e.g. `np.fmod()`, would it work for other useful `numpy` functions? Is anything off-limits?

Or should I just convert everything to floats and have done with it? Or should I go via strings?

I don't want to use pandas or Python 2.

Comment: There isn't much math defined for dates.  The difference between dates results in a timedelta (not another date).  A date plus/minus a timedelta results in a date.  Division or multiplication is not defined.

Comment: @hpaulj OK, so actually something like this is a start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865618/how-can-i-perform-divison-on-a-datetime-timedelta-in-python

Comment: What’s the context for this, what are you trying to do?